# Use style in multiple usercontrols

Tags: wpf, xaml

In my main control i defined

```
   <Control.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="TextInput" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Text" Value="{x:Static sys:String.Empty}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="PaleTurquoise" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Control.Resources>
```

How can i use this style for textBoxes in another user controls that placed inside my main control?

I dont need to apply style to ALL textboxes, but i want style that can be reused in any control i want. Is it possible without custom controls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add resources dictionary to your project.

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
   <Style x:Key="TextInput" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Text" Value="{x:Static sys:String.Empty}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="PaleTurquoise" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Then add reference to this dictionary in app resources:

```
<Application
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         x:Class="YOur class"
         StartupUri="StartupWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles\TextInputStyle.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>          
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

So, you can use your style in any part of your project

Answer (score 1):

Move your style up to the window resources

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="TextInput" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Text" Value="{x:Static sys:String.Empty}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="PaleTurquoise" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Then refer to the style like this:

```
   <TextBox Style="{StaticResource TextInput}" />
```